# Cannot select all faces sharing the same material

Tags: mesh, materials, faces

I am having some trouble with a mesh.

I start by selecting all objects:
[image]

If I move to mesh mode, and select all objects sharing the same material (plastics#car_diffuse), for some reason some faces sharing the same material are not selected:
[image]

This only happens if I first select a face from the "body" object. If I first select the mesh that is not getting selected with the material select, then the material select works fine:
[image]
[image]

I have tried merging the body object to a default cube to reset the object properties, but the problem persist. There seems to be some face data interfering with the selection but I don't know how to reset these settings back to normal.

Comment: Selecting or assigning material with several objects selected doesn't seem to work